# Delphi IDE - How to disable color for active line?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I find Delphi XE pretty stable and usable.
However, there is a 'feature' that drives me nuts!
The IDE highlights the current line in a special color. No matter that is on that line, it gets the same color.
There is any registry tweak to disable this annoying behavior?

Comment: you can also use the `Delphi IDE Theme Editor` tool  http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/delphi-ide-theme-editor/ to tweak the colors of the IDE and create your own style ;)

Comment: I personally kind of like the feature, but set the colour to a slightly lighter shade of the same hue, so it's not too distracting.

Comment: I am doing the same, only that I accidentally changed also the text color, so the text on the entire line had the same color.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the Delphi Menu Select `Tools|Options`
In the tree select `Editor Options | Color`

On the Right Top of the form is `Element` select `Line Highlight`  Where you can change the Background Color to `Default`
[image]